# How instantiate case class from Map[String, String]

Tags: scala, shapeless

Lets say I have

```
case class Sample(i:Int, b:Boolean)
```

and

```
Map[String, String]("i" => "1", "b" => "false")
```

What is most concise way to instantiate any case class(if all fields are in map), signature like this:

```
 get[T](map:[String, String]) : T
```

Probably shapeless can help acomplish this task, but I am almost unfamiliar with it. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds very similar to parsing JSON...

Comment: Yes, Hosam. It is part of CSV parser solution.

Comment: Do you need to rewrite it? There are multiple CSV parsing libraries for both Java (e.g. [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)) and Scala (e.g. [scala-csv-parser](https://index.scala-lang.org/zamblauskas/scala-csv-parser/scala-csv-parser/0.11.4?target=_2.12))

Comment: At least it was fun:) But yes,  I need custom modifications in parsing logic, so existed libs don't fit my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys. Probably I wasn't too concise. What I really need is Generic parser from Map of Strings to case class. Thanks for pointing out to LabelledGeneric. Here is solution:

```
    import shapeless.labelled.{FieldType, field}
    import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil, LabelledGeneric, Lazy, Witness}

    object FieldParser {
  trait ValParser[A] {
    def parse(str:String): A
  }

  trait FieldParser[A] {
    def parse: A
  }

  type FT[A, B] = FieldType[A, B]
  type ListField[K <: Symbol, A] = FieldType[K, List[A]]
  type FP[A] = FieldParser[A]
  type Args = (List[String],Map[String, Int])
  type Named[K <: Symbol] = Witness.Aux[K]

  private def create[A](thunk: A): FP[A] = {
    new FP[A] {
      def parse: A = thunk
    }
  }

  def apply[A](implicit st: Lazy[FP[A]]): FP[A] = st.value

  implicit def genericParser[A, R <: HList](implicit generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R], parser: Lazy[FP[R]], args:Args): FP[A] = {
    create(generic.from(parser.value.parse))
  }

  implicit def hlistParser[K <: Symbol, H, T <: HList](implicit hParser: Lazy[FP[FT[K, H]]], tParser: FP[T]): FP[FT[K, H] :: T] = {
    create {
      val hv = hParser.value.parse
      val tv = tParser.parse
      hv :: tv
    }
  }

  implicit def standardTypeParser[K <: Symbol, V:ValParser](implicit named: Named[K], args:Args): FP[FieldType[K, V]] = {
    create(field[K](implicitly[ValParser[V]].parse(findArg)))
  }

  implicit def optionParser[V](implicit valParser:ValParser[V]): ValParser[Option[V]] = new ValParser[Option[V]]{
    def parse(str:String):Option[V] = {
      str.isEmpty match {
        case true => None
        case false => Some(valParser.parse(str))
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def listParser[V](implicit valParser:ValParser[V]): ValParser[List[V]] = new ValParser[List[V]]{
    def parse(str:String):List[V] = {
      str.isEmpty match {
        case true => Nil
        case false => str.split(",").map(valParser.parse).toList
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def doubleParser: ValParser[Double] = new ValParser[Double]{
    def parse(str:String):Double = str.toDouble
  }

  implicit def intParser: ValParser[Int] = new ValParser[Int]{
    def parse(str:String):Int = str.toInt
  }

  implicit def strParser: ValParser[String] = new ValParser[String]{
    def parse(str:String):String = str
  }

  implicit def boolParser: ValParser[Boolean] = new ValParser[Boolean]{
    def parse(str:String):Boolean = str.toBoolean
  }

  implicit val hnilParser: FP[HNil] = create(HNil)

  private def findArg[K <: Symbol](implicit args:Args, named: Named[K]): String = {
    val name = named.value.name
    val index = args._2(name)
    args._1(index)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you can transform `Map[String, String]` into `Map[Symbol, Any]` and then use type classes `shapeless.ops.maps.FromMap` (or extention method `.toRecord`) and `LabelledGeneric`:

```
import shapeless.LabelledGeneric
import shapeless.record.Record
import shapeless.syntax.std.maps._

case class Sample(i: Int, b: Boolean)
val rec = Map('i -> 1, 'b -> false).toRecord[Record.`'i -> Int, 'b -> Boolean`.T].get
LabelledGeneric[Sample].from(rec) //Sample(1,false)
```

Answer (score 1):

If not using Shapeless is an option for you, you could do it in a simple way without it. Here is a sample implementation where I use the Try Monad and a pattern matching to transform the Map into your case class:

```
  (Try("1".toInt), Try("false".toBoolean)) match {
    case (Success(intVal), Success(boolVal)) =>
      Sample(intVal, boolVal)
    case _ => // Log and ignore the values
  }
```

Of course this is a bit verbose than the Shapeless version, but if you do not want to use a full library just for this simple use case, you could always do it using Scala library!